# How to serve vscode.dev with python3 -m http.server not ./scripts/code-web.sh

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-pages

I tried following code on Google Cloud Shell.

```
sudo apt -y install build-essential g++ libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev libsecret-1-dev
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vscode \
  && cd vscode \
  && nvm install 16 \
  && yarn \
  && yarn watch \
  && ./scripts/code-web.sh
```

I would like to serve it as a static file like GitHub Pages.
How can I serve vscode.dev as a static file?